# GWT + MVP4g+Ivy: compilation error

Tags: gwt, ivy, mvp4g

I have added the mvp4g jar for project through ivy configuration.It added properly and also mention   line in the gwt.xml file for mvp4g.But i am trying to compile the application it gives me following error:

> Loading inherited module 'com.mvp4g.Mvp4gModule' [ERROR] Unable to
>   find 'com/mvp4g/Mvp4gModule.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a
>   typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?
>   [ERROR] Line 13: Unexpected exception while processing element
>   'inherits' com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see
>   previous log entries) at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.nestedLoad(ModuleDefLoader.java:278)
>   at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefSchema$BodySchema.__inherits_begin(ModuleDefSchema.java:495)
>   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.HandlerMethod.invokeBegin(HandlerMethod.java:230)
>   at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.startElement(ReflectiveParser.java:294)
>   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:501)
>   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:179)
>   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1343)
>   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2755)
>   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
>   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
>   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
>   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
>   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
>   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
>   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
>   at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:347)
>   at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.access$200(ReflectiveParser.java:68)
>   at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:418)
>   at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.nestedLoad(ModuleDefLoader.java:296)
>   at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader$1.load(ModuleDefLoader.java:198)
>   at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.doLoadModule(ModuleDefLoader.java:324)
>   at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.loadFromClassPath(ModuleDefLoader.java:156)
>   at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:196) at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:170) at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:88)
>   at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:82)
>   at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:177) [ERROR] Failure
>   while parsing XML com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException:
>   (see previous log entries) at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.DefaultSchema.onHandlerException(DefaultSchema.java:58)
>   at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.Schema.onHandlerException(Schema.java:66)
>   at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.Schema.onHandlerException(Schema.java:66)
>   at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.HandlerMethod.invokeBegin(HandlerMethod.java:240)
>   at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.startElement(ReflectiveParser.java:294)
>   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:501)
>   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:179)
>   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1343)
>   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2755)
>   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
>   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
>   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
>   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
>   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
>   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
>   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
>   at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:347)
>   at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.access$200(ReflectiveParser.java:68)
>   at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:418)
>   at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.nestedLoad(ModuleDefLoader.java:296)
>   at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader$1.load(ModuleDefLoader.java:198)
>   at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.doLoadModule(ModuleDefLoader.java:324)
>   at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.loadFromClassPath(ModuleDefLoader.java:156)
>   at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:196) at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:170) at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:88)
>   at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:82)
>   at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:177) [ERROR]
>   Unexpected error while processing XML
>   com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log
>   entries) at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:371)
>   at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.access$200(ReflectiveParser.java:68)
>   at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:418)
>   at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.nestedLoad(ModuleDefLoader.java:296)
>   at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader$1.load(ModuleDefLoader.java:198)
>   at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.doLoadModule(ModuleDefLoader.java:324)
>   at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.loadFromClassPath(ModuleDefLoader.java:156)
>   at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:196) at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:170) at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:88)
>   at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:82)
>   at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:177)

Please help me on this.

Comment: have you added Mvp4gModule's jar in your java build path?

Comment: no,it added by dependency in ivy.xml.

Comment: I don't know much about Ivy but yesterday only I got the same exception. I'm using Java. So the problem was that it was expecting the jar in build path as well as at physical location (in lib folder where it goes to find all jars). & my problem got solved. Hope this information helps you.

Comment: I also tried same way my application compile properly but when i try to run it on console following two lines are coming and the url for app not generating.ERROR [Reflections] - given scan urls are empty. set urls in the configuration 
[WARN] No startup URLs supplied and no plausible ones found -- use -startupUrl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Analysis

After digging around the [project homepage](http://code.google.com/p/mvp4g/), I've discovered that the missing XML file is actually located inside the jar file:

```
unzip -t ./Mvp4g_Layout_Part2/war/WEB-INF/lib/mvp4g-1.4.0.jar | grep xml
testing: com/mvp4g/Mvp4gModule.gwt.xml   OK
testing: META-INF/maven/com.googlecode.mvp4g/mvp4g/pom.xml   OK
```

This means while the may have been downloaded by ivy, it is not present on your compile classpath.

## Assumption

You haven't specified how you're using the jar, so I must assuming the above error was thrown by the ANT **javac** task.

## Example

### ivy.xml

I'd declare the dependency in ivy and associate it with a compile configuration as follows:

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info organisation="com.myspotontheweb" module="demo"/>

    <configurations>
        <conf name="compile" description="Required to compile application"/>
    </configurations>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="com.googlecode.mvp4g" name="mvp4g" rev="1.4.0" conf="compile->default"/>
    </dependencies>

</ivy-module>
```

### build.xml

In the ANT file I'd use the ivy [cachepath](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/cachepath.html) task to create an ivy managed ANT path.

```
<target name="init">
    <ivy:resolve/>

    <ivy:report todir='${ivy.reports.dir}' graph='false' xml='false'/>

    <ivy:cachepath pathid="compile.path" conf="compile"/>
</target>
```

This path is then used as normal in the **javac** task (or any other ANT task that can accept a classpath reference)

```
<target name="compile" depends="init">
    <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" includeantruntime="false" debug="true" classpathref="compile.path"/>
</target>
```